# Definite Integral of Q function times Gaussian distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose I have an equation

\begin{equation}
y_1 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} Q(\frac{-x - b}{\sqrt{N/2}}) \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi N}} e^{- \frac{(x - a)^2}{N}} dx
\end{equation}

From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3688059/integral-of-product-of-q-function-and-normal-distribution), I can get $y_1 = Q(\frac{-a-b}{\sqrt {N}})$. But how can I calculate if it integrals over a limited interval, such as

\begin{equation}
y_2 = \int_{c}^{d} Q(\frac{-x - b}{\sqrt{N/2}}) \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi N}} e^{- \frac{(x - a)^2}{N}} dx
\end{equation}

Any responses will be appreciated.